# Minimum MacOS Version Required to Compile iOS Apps

Tags: ios, macos, compilation

We wish to compile iOS (iPhone & iPad) apps and we want to know if you need to have a minimum version of MacOS to compile/create the apps? We currently have a Mac OS X 10.6.8, 1GB RAM, 32 Bit.

If we want to compile apps for iOS 7 do we need the latest (more recent than what we have) OS?

**Edit:** Does the fact our Mac machine is 32bit affect our ability to compile iOS apps (old apps and/or more recent apps - iOS 5 and up)?

Comment: Ever since Apple prices OS upgrades to $30 (and now free) there's really no reason in your case not to bump the dev machine to the highest version supported by it. I'm not exactly sure how XCode and iOS SDK compatibility works, but for Apple I wouldn't really expect a great deal of legacy support.

Comment: For what it's worth, the version of XCode currently available in the App Store requires OS X 10.8.4 or later. You also really really really want more than 1GB RAM. I don't even remember the last time I had that amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, much appreciated. What about our Mac being 32bit, does that affect our ability to compile iOS apps?

Comment: In and of itself it probably doesn't. It does however imply your Mac is pretty antiquated, and it might mean it can't be upgraded to a recent OS X version.

Comment: On a more constructive note. A Mac Mini costs $600. That's a fraction of a single developer's monthly salary. If your application isn't worth that much money there's probably no point in making it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we want to compile apps for iOS 7 do we need the latest (more recent than what we have) OS?

Compiling apps against the iOS 7 SDK requires Xcode 5.  Xcode 5 requires 10.8.4 or later.  You have provided insufficient information about your Mac to determine if your Mac can run OS X 10.8.  [Try to install Mavericks here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/os-x-mavericks/id675248567?mt=12), or if that doesn't work [see the Mountain Lion requirements and buy it here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion).

Comment: Also, the cost of your development machine is a drop in the bucket compared to your total development costs.  Buy the best one, or your developers will hate you because you will lose 45 seconds every time you recompile (which may be hundreds of times a day).

Comment: +1 for the above comment. Also equipment costs should count as tax-deductible expenses, while employee salaries come with income tax and a bunch of other non-deductible add-ons on top of them. (Depending on your country's tax code of course.)

Comment: I know developers that have gotten a new job just so they don't have to use a year-old laptop.  I'm not saying it's mature, but it happens, and employee retention is really important when building software.

Comment: Well, another way of looking at that is that it shows what the company cares about. If you're being given the cheapest gear that lets you kinda sorta get the work done, that means the company cares about the bottom line more than its employees. And it's not really the "grunt" developer's responsibility to give two craps about the company's bottom line – the executives are paid to do that, and management is paid to make sure the developers never need to. (Although, bailing for 1 year old hardware *is* petty and wasteful.)

Answer (score 2):

iOS7 SDK requires XCode 5 (min requirement 10.8.4)

OSX 10.6.8 will not run anything beyond XCode 4.2

Answer (score 0):

**OS X 10.6.8 (snow leopard) is TOO OLD to publish an iphone app.**

You'll need a new mac with OS X 10.8 (mountain lion). If the hardware in your mac won't support an upgrade to more recent OS X versions, don't waste your time. Apple have not maintained backward compatibility: the minimum versions of Xcode or Application Launcher needed to meet the app store requirements won't run on 10.6.8.

Specifically:
- Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK

You can develop, test and simulate with your old mac, but ultimately to build and publish your app you'll need a newer Mac.

Answer (score 0):

**2022 update**

Now they require SDK 15, included in XCode 13 or later (https://xcodereleases.com).

This release requires macOS Big Sur 11.3 which can officially work on macs from 2013 and later: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211238

In fact you can install it on an older mac with a patch, such as: https://github.com/dortania/Opencore-Legacy-Patcher